# Create thumbnail seek/scrubber bar with SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, avfoundation, seekbar, seekbar-thumb

I need a help in creation thumbnail seek/scrubber bar based on SwiftUI. Looking for something similar on native Photos app when we watch some video. So currently I'm already done with thumbnails and placed it at my view (but I'm not confident is it done in right way):

```swift
ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
    ScrollView(.horizontal) {
        HStack {
            ForEach(0..<thumbnails.count, id: \.self) { index in
                Image(uiImage: thumbnails[index])
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                    .frame(width: 33, height: 40)
            }
        }
        .padding(.bottom, 18)
        .overlay(alignment: .leading) {
            Rectangle()
                .fill(Color.white)
                .frame(width: 4, height: 44)
                .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                .contentShape(Rectangle())
                .cornerRadius(10)
                .overlay(
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                        .inset(by: 0.5)
                        .stroke(Color.black, lineWidth: 1)
                )
                .offset(x: videoSize.width * progress)
                .padding(.bottom, 18)
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

As I see I need to find proper width and/or offset values, tracking progress but I'm stuck at this. Also I need somehow handle my dragGesture, when I move my Rectangle() it will slide over images.

I'll really appreciate if you give me some advices or show right direction!

Comment: I don't think it is feasible to get the actual scroll position of a SwiftUI ScrollView AND sync that with an AVPlayer in real-time (with reasonable performance). I've implemented this twice and (in both cases) ended up with a UIKit UIScrollView in a UIViewRepresentable (and never exposing the real-time scroll position to SwiftUI).